# Rspec test NameError: uninitialized constant trying to tie a class into a rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

So I"m not too familiar with ruby or rspec, and I have an rspect test, and here is a code snippet from it:

```
describe 'thingMagic' do 
    let(:tester) { testClass.testing }
    it { expect(tester).to be whatever doesn't matter at this point
```

So I wrote a class called `testClass` with a method called `testing` in it. Here's what it looks like:

```
class testClass
  def testing
    return pass_test
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out when I run rspec it is failing with this error in the console:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:tester) { testClass.testing }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant testClass
```

I can't seem to figure out how to initialize this class. Is there a file I have to modify in rspec giving it a relative path to this file?

Comment: it sorta did. I found out I needed a require_relative '<path_to_file'>. reference: http://ruby.about.com/od/faqs/qt/Nameerror-Uninitialized-Constant-Object-Something.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of Googling and sheer luck. I learned:
I needed:

```
require_relative '<path_to_file>'
```

after I added that into the spec.rb file. I re-ran the rspec test and it started working.

Here was good documentation and basically made me realized what I missed:
http://ruby.about.com/od/faqs/qt/Nameerror-Uninitialized-Constant-Object-Something.htm

Comment: I have upvoted this because it works, although in general it is a last resort. The error normally means your rspec configuration is missing something.